# how to use js in smarty template?

Tags: javascript, templates, attributes, smarty

Using html_options how to add id or class attribute to it and how to use javascript in smarty
specifically I need to perform some action on html_option change.
in my .php file i have the following piece code:

```
<script ....>
function changeProvince(){
        var province = document.getElementById("addr_province");
        province.addEventListener("change", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
    }
changeProvince();
</script>
```

and in my .tpl file

```
{{html_options name=addr_province options=$addr_province id="addr_province"}}
```

With the above piece of code
it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to use:

```
{html_options name=addr_province options=$addr_province id="addr_province"}

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeProvince(){
        var province = document.getElementById("addr_province");
        province.addEventListener("change", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
    }
changeProvince();
</script>
```

but as you see you need to create first options, and then run `changeProvince();` JavaScript function.

Other way you get JavaScript error `TypeError: province is null` and simple it won't work.

**EDIT**

If you want, you can do it also this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeProvince(){
        var province = document.getElementById("addr_province");
        province.addEventListener("change", function(){ alert("Hello World!"); });
    }
</script>

{html_options name=addr_province options=$addr_province id="addr_province"}

<script type="text/javascript">
changeProvince();
</script>
```

You can define your function earlier but run it after creating select and options

Comment: Shall i put my js code inside .tpl file as here in your answer? currently my js code is in the php file and the tpl file is included using $smarty->display(tpl file);

Comment: You could place this JavaScript in Smarty file. Error is visible only on JavaScript console.